# Not booting into grub (boot-repair log included)

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, boot-repair

Yesterday, after having resized and moved some of my partitions I have successfully enlarged my Ubuntu partition but in the morning I wanted to launch the computer and ... one thing I get is the "blinking beacon".

I have tried booting into Ubuntu 12.04 USB and it worked, the disk is working - I can access it's files but I cannot boot into it.

I have tried using `boot-repair` but with the automated option I get no luck.

This is the link to it's log http://paste.ubuntu.com/1155008/

Can anyone help me on this ?

I have been thinking on creating separate `/boot` partition in the beginning of the disk but I have some other Windows related partitions there (e.g. recovery partition) and this might be problematic.

**EDIT**
After clicking `Restore MBR` in `boot-repair` I can boot but only to windows:/

Another `boot-repair` [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1155024/)

**EDIT**

I have plugged in a USB stick in and installed my GRUB on it, then I was able to boot my Ubuntu (from hard drive) with GRUB from USB stick.

Now, since I already have access to my system - how can I repair/restore GRUB from here ? (or maybe even from anywhere else ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your booted Ubuntu install, run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.

While it's possible that you also have a buggy BIOS and need a separate /boot partition that is *not* what is causing the problem here (if that were the problem, you would still get a grub rescue shell rather than just a blinking cursor) and therefore I would recommend  *not* creating a separate /boot partition (at least until you find that you really do have a buggy BIOS which can't properly handle large disks).

Comment: I have tried this and I got this [warn: Your embedding area is unusually small.  core.img won't fit in it..](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1157983/)
[Debug version of this log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1157988/)

Comment: Ok so the problem was that somehow I have moved my first partition so that it would start in 19th sector instead of 63rd (I believe) and grub did not have enough place to install itself. Your answer is good but I needed to dig a little to figure this out and move my first partition a bit.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 more boot recover options: http://www.supergrubdisk.org

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Boot-Repair in its final window:

```
The boot files of [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk.
Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot
partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools
such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:]
option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

If I were you, I would:

1. backup documents on an external drive (or DVDs)
2. via `Gparted` (included in Ubuntu CD) format the `sda1` partition (labelled `PQSERVICE`) into EXT4.
3. launch `Boot-Repair`, click `Advanced options`, go to the `GRUB location`
   tab, tick the `Separate /boot partition: sda1` option, click
   `Apply`. Write the new URL on a paper (indicate it if any problem).

Comment: This is the option that I wanted to avoid :/ Will the option with `separate partition` appear when I create a new one/format existing into ext4 (3) ? Because now I cannot see this option in the `boot-repair`

Comment: I think so. Boot-Repair doesn't propose separate /boot in NTFS.

Comment: Ok I have found that option when plugged a USB stick in. Please check my update.